# MySQL - Create a function from another function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, functions

I want to create a function same like my old functions.

When I create a table, I can use `AS  to other table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy2 AS SELECT * FROM dummy1;
```

Can I do the same thing with functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could play some games with `mysql.proc`, the physical home of all Stored Procedures and Stored Functions.

First, here are the databases on my PC

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| david              |
| dufran             |
| jimelliott         |
| junk               |
| karto              |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| preeti             |
| rolando            |
| sandro             |
| telwit             |
| telwit_french      |
| test               |
| user1162541        |
| yellowseason       |
+--------------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Let's create a Stored Function in the database `rolando` called `GetUnixTimeStamp`:

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetUnixTimeStamp` $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetUnixTimeStamp`(x INT) RETURNS int(11)
    -> DETERMINISTIC
    -> BEGIN
    ->     RETURN UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> SELECT rolando.GetUnixTimeStamp(9);
+-----------------------------+
| rolando.GetUnixTimeStamp(9) |
+-----------------------------+
|                  1352263567 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Let's try to sculpt the CREATE FUNCTION SQL Statement based on the function itself

```
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE DEFINER=`',REPLACE(definer,'@','`@`'),
'` ',type,' `',db,'`.`',name,'`(',param_list,') ',
IF(type='FUNCTION',CONCAT('RETURNS ',returns),''),' ',
IF(is_deterministic='YES','DETERMINISTIC',''),' ',body)
INTO @ProcedureCreationSQL from mysql.proc
WHERE db='rolando' AND name='GetUnixTimeSTamp';
SELECT @ProcedureCreationSQL\G
```

What does this generate ?

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('CREATE DEFINER=`',REPLACE(definer,'@','`@`'),
    -> '` ',type,' `',db,'`.`',name,'`(',param_list,') ',
    -> IF(type='FUNCTION',CONCAT('RETURNS ',returns),''),' ',
    -> IF(is_deterministic='YES','DETERMINISTIC',''),' ',body)
    -> INTO @ProcedureCreationSQL from mysql.proc
    -> WHERE db='rolando' AND name='GetUnixTimeSTamp';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @ProcedureCreationSQL\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@ProcedureCreationSQL: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `rolando`.`GetUnixTimeStamp`(x INT) RETURNS int(11) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN
    RETURN UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
END
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK so far, so good. Let's change the SQL to place this function in the database `david`

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('CREATE DEFINER=`',REPLACE(definer,'@','`@`'),
    -> '` ',type,' `david`.`',name,'`(',param_list,') ',
    -> IF(type='FUNCTION',CONCAT('RETURNS ',returns),''),' ',
    -> IF(is_deterministic='YES','DETERMINISTIC',''),' ',body)
    -> INTO @ProcedureCreationSQL from mysql.proc
    -> WHERE db='rolando' AND name='GetUnixTimeSTamp';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @ProcedureCreationSQL\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@ProcedureCreationSQL: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `david`.`GetUnixTimeStamp`(x INT) RETURNS int(11) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN
    RETURN UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
END
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK Great. We can make the SQL. Can I execute the creation of the new function ???

```
echo DELIMITER $$ > newproc.txt
mysql -uroot --delimiter="$$" -ANe"SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT('CREATE DEFINER=`',REPLACE(definer,'@','`@`'),'` ',type,' `david`.`',name,'`(',param_list,') ',IF(type='FUNCTION',CONCAT('RETURNS ',returns),''),' ',IF(is_deterministic='YES','DETERMINISTIC',''),' ',body),'\n',' ') from mysql.proc WHERE db='rolando' AND name='GetUnixTimeSTamp';" >> newproc.txt
echo $$ >> newproc.txt
mysql -uroot < newproc.txt
```

Does the function exist ???

```
mysql> show create function david.getunixtimestamp\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            Function: getunixtimestamp
            sql_mode:
     Create Function: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getunixtimestamp`(x INT) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN     RETURN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(); END
character_set_client: cp850
collation_connection: cp850_general_ci
  Database Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Biggest questiion of all : Does the newly copied function run ???

```
mysql> select david.getunixtimestamp(8);
+---------------------------+
| david.getunixtimestamp(8) |
+---------------------------+
|                1352265404 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

HOORAY !!! This is how you can copy a function from one database to another.

FINAL QUESTION : Is this all worth it ???

## SUMMARY

Here is the original SQL to generate function creation

```
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE DEFINER=`',REPLACE(definer,'@','`@`'),
'` ',type,' `david`.`',name,'`(',param_list,') ',
IF(type='FUNCTION',CONCAT('RETURNS ',returns),''),' ',
IF(is_deterministic='YES','DETERMINISTIC',''),' ',body)
INTO @ProcedureCreationSQL from mysql.proc
WHERE db='rolando' AND name='GetUnixTimeSTamp';
SELECT @ProcedureCreationSQL\G
```

This will create Stored Procedures as well

Here is the copy operation, which must take place from the OS level calling the mysql client

```
echo DELIMITER $$ > newproc.txt
mysql -uroot --delimiter="$$" -ANe"SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT('CREATE DEFINER=`',REPLACE(definer,'@','`@`'),'` ',type,' `david`.`',name,'`(',param_list,') ',IF(type='FUNCTION',CONCAT('RETURNS ',returns),''),' ',IF(is_deterministic='YES','DETERMINISTIC',''),' ',body),'\n',' ') from mysql.proc WHERE db='rolando' AND name='GetUnixTimeSTamp';" >> newproc.txt
echo $$ >> newproc.txt
mysql -uroot < newproc.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Get the SQL script when the function / procedure was created

```
SHOW CREATE FUNCTION my_schema_1.my_function;
```

We will get an result looks like

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mysqladmin`@`%` FUNCTION `my_function`
    (i_paramter1 char(255), i_paramter2 int) 
    RETURNS char(3) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

  DECLARE result_value char(3);

  SELECT if(count(*) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') into result_value
    FROM
      ...
    where 
      ...
  ;
return result_value;

END
```

**Step 2**.

- Add the target schema, say `my_schema_2` to the code
- At beginning add one line `delimiter $$`
- After the last line add one line `$$`

As

```
delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER=`mysqladmin`@`%` FUNCTION `my_schema_2`.`my_function`
...
... (same as above)
...
...
END
$$
```

**Step 3**. Run the generated SQL Script to generate the function again in the target schema `my_schema_2`

See the help document here

- [MySQL SHOW CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-function.html)
- [MySQL SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-procedure.html)